# telethon python mark messages as read

Tags: telegram, telethon

I have the following code to get messages from group:

```py
getmessage = client.get_messages(dialog, limit=1000)
    for message in getmessage:
        try:
            if message.media == None:
                print("message")
                continue
            else:
                print("Media**********")
                client.download_media(message)
```

I'm running this code each 1 min, I received same messages each running, How can I get only new messages (from last running)?

Comment: You want to store a "seen message ID" somewhere outside of your loop so that next time you loop, you can skip them if the message ID is less than or equal to said ID. But this sounds like you should be using `events`.

Comment: how can I do it using events?

Comment: I encourage you to take a look at https://docs.telethon.dev/.

Comment: hmm, so if i need to schedule my code each 1 min the only solution i have is to save the last message id?